# Does Apache Flink AWS S3 Sink require Hadoop for local testing?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am relatively new to Apache Flink and I am trying to create a simple project that produces a file to an AWS S3 bucket. Based on the documentation it looks like I am required to have Hadoop installed in order to do this.

How do I set up my local environment to allow me to test this capability? I have installed Apache Flink as well as Hadoop locally. I have added the necessary changes to the core-site.xml configuration for Hadoop and also added my HADOOP_CONF path to my flink.yaml configuration. When I try and submit my job locally through the Flink UI I always get an error

```html
2016-12-29 16:03:49,861 INFO  org.apache.flink.util.NetUtils                                - Unable to allocate on port 6123, due to error: Address already in use
2016-12-29 16:03:49,862 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager                - Failed to run JobManager.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to do further retries starting the actor system
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.retryOnBindException(JobManager.scala:2203)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.runJobManager(JobManager.scala:2143)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$.main(JobManager.scala:2040)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager.main(JobManager.scala)
```

I am assuming that I am missing something with how my environment is set up. Is it possible to do this locally? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check if port 6123 is in use. If its not then disable your firewall/iptables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you need Hadoop libraries you do not have to have Hadoop installed to run locally and write to S3. I just happened to try this out with writing a Parquet output based on Avro schema and generated SpecificRecord to S3. I am running a version of the following code locally through SBT and Intellij Idea. Needed parts:

1) Have the following file specifying the needed Hadoop properties (Note: defining the AWS access key/secret key is not recommended. Better to run on an EC2 instance that has proper IAM role to read/write to your S3 bucket. But needed for local for testing)

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Comma separated list of local directories used to buffer
         large results prior to transmitting them to S3. -->
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.buffer.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp</value>
    </property>

    <!-- set your AWS ID using key defined in org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Constants -->
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <value>YOUR_ACCESS_KEY</value>
    </property>

    <!-- set your AWS access key -->
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <value>YOUR_SECRET_KEY</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

2) Imports:
    import com.uebercomputing.eventrecord.EventOnlyRecord

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopOutputFormat
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.{ExecutionEnvironment, _}

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.{Configuration => HadoopConfiguration}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job

import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetOutputFormat
```

3) Flink code uses HadoopOutputFormat with above configuration:

```
    val events: DataSet[(Void, EventOnlyRecord)] = ...

    val hadoopConfig = getHadoopConfiguration(hadoopConfigFile)

    val outputFormat = new AvroParquetOutputFormat[EventOnlyRecord]
    val outputJob = Job.getInstance

    //Note: AvroParquetOutputFormat extends FileOutputFormat[Void,T]
    //so key is Void, value of type T - EventOnlyRecord in this case
    val hadoopOutputFormat = new HadoopOutputFormat[Void, EventOnlyRecord](
      outputFormat,
      outputJob
    )

    val outputConfig = outputJob.getConfiguration
    outputConfig.addResource(hadoopConfig)
    val outputPath = new Path("s3://<bucket>/<dir-prefix>")
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(outputJob, outputPath)
    AvroParquetOutputFormat.setSchema(outputJob, EventOnlyRecord.getClassSchema)

    events.output(hadoopOutputFormat)

    env.execute

    ...

    def getHadoopConfiguration(hadoodConfigPath: String): HadoopConfiguration = {
      val hadoopConfig = new HadoopConfiguration()
      hadoopConfig.addResource(new Path(hadoodConfigPath))
      hadoopConfig
    }
```

4) Build dependencies and versions used:

```
    val awsSdkVersion = "1.7.4"
    val hadoopVersion = "2.7.3"
    val flinkVersion = "1.1.4"

    val flinkDependencies = Seq(
      ("org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion),
      ("org.apache.flink" %% "flink-hadoop-compatibility" % flinkVersion)
    )

    val providedFlinkDependencies = flinkDependencies.map(_ % "provided")

    val serializationDependencies = Seq(
      ("org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.7.7"),
      ("org.apache.avro" % "avro-mapred" % "1.7.7").classifier("hadoop2"),
      ("org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-avro" % "1.8.1")
    )

    val s3Dependencies = Seq(
      ("com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % awsSdkVersion),
      ("org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % hadoopVersion)
    )
```

## Edit for using writeAsText to S3:

1) Create a Hadoop configuration directory (will reference this as hadoop-conf-dir) with a file core-site.xml in it.

For example:

```
mkdir /home/<user>/hadoop-config
cd /home/<user>/hadoop-config
vi core-site.xml

#content of core-site.xml 
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Comma separated list of local directories used to buffer
         large results prior to transmitting them to S3. -->
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.buffer.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp</value>
    </property>

    <!-- set your AWS ID using key defined in org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Constants -->
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <value>YOUR_ACCESS_KEY</value>
    </property>

    <!-- set your AWS access key -->
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <value>YOUR_SECRET_KEY</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

2) Create a directory (will reference this as flink-conf-dir) with a file flink-conf.yaml in it.

For example:

```
mkdir /home/<user>/flink-config
cd /home/<user>/flink-config
vi flink-conf.yaml

//content of flink-conf.yaml - continuing earlier example
fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: /home/<user>/hadoop-config
```

3) Edit your IntelliJ Run configuration used to run your S3 Flink job - Run - Edit configurations -  and add the following environment variable:

```
FLINK_CONF_DIR and set it to your flink-conf-dir

Continuing the example above:
FLINK_CONF_DIR=/home/<user>/flink-config
```

4) Run the code with that environment variable set:

```
events.writeAsText("s3://<bucket>/<prefix-dir>")

env.execute
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there a way that I can just point my local java execution to the hadoop configuration file without defining the outputPath. Based on the documentation it seems like I should be able to just do something like: messageStream.writeAsText("s3://..."); but when I run a local execution through IntelliJ it has no idea where that file is. I also can't seem to find any flink operation that will allow me to set it at run time.

Comment: The problem is that the default HadoopFileSystem being used when you call writeAsText does not "know" about the s3 file system.  See edit to my original answer above.

Comment: So I think I got everything working, but I am having access issues to my S3 bucket. with this error:
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: **********, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: 

I am not sure why its having an access error, as the keys used in my app are the same account that created the S3 bucket. It seems that everything is working now on the flink side. If you have any tips on why I am getting this error let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: @medium maybe different IAM permissions for creating a bucket than putting an object into a bucket? See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html. Can you write from the AWS CLI (https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with those keys? "aws s3 cp <localfile> s3://<your-bucket>/" Sounds like the Flink part is set up now.

Comment: Please help me know how to do this for a flink application which is running in a flink cluster environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following to run my flink job locally which sinks to S3:

1- Added flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.9.1.jar to my flink/plugins/flink-s3-fs-hadoop directory

2- Modified flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml to include 
s3.access-key: AWS_ACCESS_KEY
s3.secret-key: AWS_SECRET_KEY
fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: /etc/hadoop-config

I have the core-site.xml file in hadoop-config folder but it does not include any configurations so fs.hdfs.hadoopconf might not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

In sbt I just need to add the S3 library dependencies to use it like a local file system

SBT file:

`"org.apache.flink" % "flink-s3-fs-hadoop" % flinkVersion.value`

Reading example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataStream<String> text = env.readTextFile("s3://etl-data-ia/test/fileStreamTest.csv");
    text.print();
    env.execute("test");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on that link https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#hadooppresto-s3-file-systems-plugins

> To use flink-s3-fs-hadoop plugin you should copy the respective JAR
> file from the opt directory to the plugins directory of your Flink
> distribution before starting Flink.

another way I know is to enable it via environment variable
ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS="flink-s3-fs-hadoop-[flink-version].jar"

for example: flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.12.2.jar

For both ways we have to define S3 configurations in flink-conf.yaml file

> Flink will internally translate this back to fs.s3a.connection.maximum. There is no need to pass configuration parameters using Hadoop’s XML configuration files.

```
s3.endpoint: <end-point>
s3.path.style.access : true
```

As for AWS credentials , they must be provided either in environment variable or. configured in flink-conf.yaml

```
s3.endpoint: <end-point>
s3.path.style.access : true
s3.access-key: <key>
s3.secret-key: <value>
s3.region: <region>
```

Once its all set you can read from S3 as @EyalP mentioned, or write to S3(i.e with dataset)

```
dataset.map(new MapToJsonString())
                .writeAsText("s3://....",
                        FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE);
```

If you would like to test it locally (Without real AWS account) i'd suggest you to check [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack). it fully supports various AWS services (S3 included). if you go with that, then the AWS credentials are not necessary(may provided empty) and endpoint will be the localstack itself.