# [Apache Flink]: Where is flink-s3-fs-hadoop plugin?

Tags: apache-flink

I would like to **read and write** some data with **Apache Flink 1.11.2 from S3**. The documentation recommends to use the presto plugin for checkpoints and the hadoop plugin for pipeline data.

After reading [this section](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/filesystems/#pluggable-file-systems) you have to copy the plugins from `/opt` to `/plugin`. I can find the `flink-s3-fs-presto-1.11.2.jar` under /opt but there is no `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.11.2.jar`. Where can i find the s3-hadoop plugin for setting up  my production environment?

And how can i use these plugins in the IDE? Simply adding these to pom.xml als provided dependencies? And then how can i pass the crentials in IDE?

Answer (score 1):

That is weird I can see that they are both present in the official binaries in `opt` in 1.11.1. However if You can't find them, You can simply try to get the jars from Maven [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-s3-fs-hadoop/1.11.2) and copy them to the required place. Another thing that may work is adding the dependency into the project with `compile` scope.

Running the job locally is described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/hadoop.html). There are various ways of configuring the credentials when running the job in IDE, one might be adding `core-site.xml` to resources folder with proper configruation.

EDIT:
As for the local execution it was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388003/does-apache-flink-aws-s3-sink-require-hadoop-for-local-testing) a little bit.

Comment: Yeah, in version 1.11.1 the plugin is in the `/opt` folder. The link you posted is not helpful, because i don't want to read/write from hadoop. I just want to test my flink job in IDE which is reading from S3.

Comment: Added Edit about local execution

Comment: Okay, thank you. So i can reference the ``/conf/flink-conf.yml` in my IntelliJ via `FLINK_CONF_DIR` env variable?

Comment: is your flik reading or writing s3 working ? I am facing issue so want to check.